# How to get a Hexo-built site variables in a pug template?

Tags: pug, templating, hexo, pugjs

I have a Pug template (for what will become the root `index.html`) which is supposed to just list the titles of my posts:

```
p first line of the page

ul
    each post in site.posts
        li= post.title

p last line of the page
```

When building the site I get in `index.html`

```
<p>first line of the page</p>
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
<p>last line of the page</p>
```

I have two posts on this site and the two `<li></li>` suggest that I iterate over the right variable (and that the variable is known).

How can I get the content of these elements from Array `site.posts`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is [a bug](https://github.com/hexojs/hexo/issues/3038), the following works:

```
p first line of the page

ul
    each i in site.posts.data
        li= i.title
```