# What is a "Something { key: value, SomethingElse { key: value, ...}}" structure?

Tags: javascript, pug, hexo

I am trying to build a blog with [Hexo](https://hexo.io), using [Pug](https://pugjs.org) as the templating engine. I [do not understand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48903549/how-to-get-a-hexo-built-site-variables-in-a-pug-template) how to access global variables (defined in Hexo) and ended up adding some JavaScript to debug the output.

In Hexo, the `site` variable holds information about the site being used. This is a JavaScript powered static blog generator and it is possible to inject JS during the processing. I wanted the `site` variable to be output on the console (`_` is the global for Lodash) while processing a template:

```
_.forEach(site, function (po) {
        console.log('post info', po)
    })
```

The output I am getting is (I broke apart the `post info` chunks):

```
post info Query {
  data:
   [ Document {
       title: 'first article',
       layout: 'mypost',
       _content: '\nThis is the first article',
       source: '_posts/first.md',
       raw: '---\ntitle: first article\ntags: tech\nlayout: mypost\n---\n\nThis is the first article',
       slug: 'first',
       published: true,
       date: moment("2018-02-20T20:57:27.120"),
       updated: moment("2018-02-22T09:19:24.597"),
       comments: true,
       photos: [],
       link: '',
       _id: 'cjdy8m62w00005ondnc5md94c',
       content: '<p>This is the first article</p>\n',
       site: [Object],
       excerpt: '',
       more: '<p>This is the first article</p>\n',
       path: [Getter],
       permalink: [Getter],
       full_source: [Getter],
       asset_dir: [Getter],
       tags: [Getter],
       categories: [Getter],
       prev: [Object],
       __post: true,
       lang: null,
       canonical_path: '2018/02/20/first/index.html' },
     Document {
       title: 'Hello World 2',
       _content: '\nSecond article comes here',
       source: '_posts/second.md',
       raw: '---\ntitle: Hello World 2\ntags: tech\n---\n\nSecond article comes here',
       slug: 'second',
       published: true,
       date: moment("2018-02-20T23:05:52.156"),
       updated: moment("2018-02-22T09:19:48.205"),
       comments: true,
       layout: 'post',
       photos: [],
       link: '',
       _id: 'cjdy8m63300015ond87428rhr',
       content: '<p>Second article comes here</p>\n',
       site: [Object],
       excerpt: '',
       more: '<p>Second article comes here</p>\n',
       path: [Getter],
       permalink: [Getter],
       full_source: [Getter],
       asset_dir: [Getter],
       tags: [Getter],
       categories: [Getter],
       next: [Object],
       __post: true,
       lang: null,
       canonical_path: '2018/02/20/second/index.html' } ],
  length: 2 }

post info Query { data: [], length: 0 }

post info Model {
  domain: null,
  _events: {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  name: 'Category',
  data: {},
  _mutex: Mutex { _locked: false, _queue: [] },
  schema:
   Schema {
     paths:
      { name: [Object],
        parent: [Object],
        slug: [Object],
        path: [Object],
        permalink: [Object],
        posts: [Object],
        length: [Object],
        _id: [Object] },
     statics: {},
     methods: {},
     hooks: { pre: [Object], post: [Object] },
     stacks:
      { getter: [Array],
        setter: [Array],
        import: [Array],
        export: [Array] } },
  length: 0,
  Document: { [Function] super_: [Function: Document] },
  Query: { [Function] super_: [Function: Query] } }

post info Model {
  domain: null,
  _events: {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  name: 'Tag',
  data:
   { cjdy8m63600025ondq69zill9: { name: 'tech', _id: 'cjdy8m63600025ondq69zill9' } },
  _mutex: Mutex { _locked: false, _queue: [] },
  schema:
   Schema {
     paths:
      { name: [Object],
        slug: [Object],
        path: [Object],
        permalink: [Object],
        posts: [Object],
        length: [Object],
        _id: [Object] },
     statics: {},
     methods: {},
     hooks: { pre: [Object], post: [Object] },
     stacks:
      { getter: [Array],
        setter: [Array],
        import: [Array],
        export: [Array] } },
  length: 1,
  Document: { [Function] super_: [Function: Document] },
  Query: { [Function] super_: [Function: Query] } }

post info {}
```

I am at loss as to what `Query`, `Model`, `Schema` and `Document` are, and how to access the data within.

What follows either of them seem to be an Object (with key and values separated by a colon), but it also contains sutructures such as

```
schema:
 Schema {
   paths:
    { name: [Object],
    (...)
```

which I do not understand (the `Schema {` part, specifically).

**What kind of data structure is that and how to access its contents?**

Comment: They're [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes).

Comment: @Nit: thank you. I deleted my other comments as I found on my own how to address the members of what I think being an instance of a class (in my case). Would you mind just bootstrap an answer which i would edit to add some details?

Comment: You can answer your own question with all the details, that's completely fine on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Nit: yes I know, I do it all the time when I find an answer on my own to my own question. I also like to give quantifiable credit to those who help me, usually asking that they just boostrap an answer (usually with their comment) and I then update it with the details. This way it is more useful for the next ones and rep credit goes where due. But I will be glad to take your comment and do it on my own - thanks for the solution BTW!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These entities are [Javascript classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes).
When a class instance is logged to the browser console, its class name is preserved, that's a part of why good naming is often very useful for debugging. See the following example:

```js
class Foo {
  // Define methods and properties
}
const instance = new Foo();
// Will log `{}` in the snippet console, but `Foo {}` in the browser console.
console.log(instance);
```